# Team Fortress 2: Crafting Recipes

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm looking for some good crafting recipes for TF2. I know the ones that give you stock, which isn't much, and I've looked in the TF2 wiki, but I wondered if anyone has found some good recipes and would like to share?

Comment: wow, i didn't even realize you can craft...i am so behind the times when it comes to TF2 :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the official tf2 wiki [lists them all](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting), and that page is updated very quickly when new items are added... so I have a feeling you'd have a very hard time finding a recipe which isn't there.

Also, in case you missed it, there's a very convenient "Cost summary table" on that page, which shows you the total cost for achiving a certain item (e.g. you can see that crafting a weapon "costs" 8 other weapons).

Comment: It should be worth mentioning that not only does the wiki list all the craftable items in their entirety, but it also lists the items that are in game that are not craftable at all and how to obtain them (if you even can).

Answer (score 2):

Also **TF2Items.com** has a [good list](http://www.tf2items.com/crafting/blueprints.php) of recipes. In addition it has other features like Backpack Examiner.

Comment: I didn't know the Ban Hammer was an Engie weapon.